# Create fake DB from laravel seed

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to create DB with fake data without using any migrations.

my tables are divided into two types.

**Tables with model** : This I know their solution with use faker and model class like this example :

```
        $user->posts()->save(factory(App\Post::class)->make());
    });
```

***Tables without model*** : I don't know how I can use DB facade to create tables and generate same fake data in the same time

Comment: well you can execute DB statements with it ...

Comment: @lagbox how can I generate fake data with DB statements?